# Enrich Mediator applies on First element only in WSO2 ESB 5

Tags: xml, xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using `Enrich Mediator` to Enrich an XML.

My problem is, it always applies to the first element only although I want to apply it to multiple elements. How can I apply it to all the elements selected by XPATH?

I tried below option too. But fails.

```
//Response/ResponseDetails/SearchHotelPriceResponse/HotelDetails/Hotel[@HasExtraInfo="true"]
```

**Enrich configuration :**

```
<enrich>
    <source type="inline">
        <ImageCode xmlns="">IMG10004</ImageCode>
    </source>
    <target action="child" xpath="//Response/ResponseDetails/SearchHotelPriceResponse/HotelDetails/Hotel[*]"/>
</enrich>
```

**XML Payload :**

```
<Response ResponseReference="REF_D_028_749-2801486459143247">
    <ResponseDetails Language="en">
        <SearchHotelPriceResponse>
            <HotelDetails>
                <Hotel HasExtraInfo="true" HasMap="true" HasPictures="true">
                    <City Code="LON">London</City>
                    <Item Code="ALE1">ALEXANDRA</Item>
                    <StarRating>3</StarRating>
                    <HotelRooms>
                        <HotelRoom Code="SB" NumberOfRooms="1"/>
                    </HotelRooms>
                </Hotel>
                <Hotel HasExtraInfo="true" HasPictures="true">
                    <City Code="LON">London</City>
                    <Item Code="ALO">Aloft London Excel</Item>
                    <StarRating>4</StarRating>
                    <HotelRooms>
                        <HotelRoom Code="SB" NumberOfRooms="1"/>
                    </HotelRooms>
                </Hotel>
                <Hotel HasExtraInfo="true" HasMap="true" HasPictures="true">
                    <City Code="LON">London</City>
                    <Item Code="AMB3">Ambassadors Bloomsbury</Item>
                    <StarRating>4</StarRating>
                    <HotelRooms>
                        <HotelRoom Code="SB" NumberOfRooms="1"/>
                    </HotelRooms>
                </Hotel>
            </HotelDetails>
        </SearchHotelPriceResponse>
    </ResponseDetails>
</Response>
```

- ESB version 5.0.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "iterate" mediator with aggregate for proccess all elements. Please check my solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="EnrichProxy"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <Response xmlns="" ResponseReference="REF_D_028_749-2801486459143247">
                  <ResponseDetails Language="en">
                     <SearchHotelPriceResponse>
                        <HotelDetails>
                           <Hotel HasExtraInfo="false" HasMap="true" HasPictures="true">
                              <City Code="LON">London</City>
                              <Item Code="ALE1">ALEXANDRA</Item>
                              <StarRating>3</StarRating>
                              <HotelRooms>
                                 <HotelRoom Code="SB" NumberOfRooms="1"/>
                              </HotelRooms>
                           </Hotel>
                           <Hotel HasExtraInfo="true" HasPictures="true">
                              <City Code="LON">London</City>
                              <Item Code="ALO">Aloft London Excel</Item>
                              <StarRating>4</StarRating>
                              <HotelRooms>
                                 <HotelRoom Code="SB" NumberOfRooms="1"/>
                              </HotelRooms>
                           </Hotel>
                           <Hotel HasExtraInfo="true" HasMap="true" HasPictures="true">
                              <City Code="LON">London</City>
                              <Item Code="AMB3">Ambassadors Bloomsbury</Item>
                              <StarRating>4</StarRating>
                              <HotelRooms>
                                 <HotelRoom Code="SB" NumberOfRooms="1"/>
                              </HotelRooms>
                           </Hotel>
                        </HotelDetails>
                     </SearchHotelPriceResponse>
                  </ResponseDetails>
               </Response>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property expression="$body" name="bodyBackup" type="OM"/>
         <iterate expression="$body//Response/ResponseDetails/SearchHotelPriceResponse/HotelDetails/Hotel"
                  id="Hotels">
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <filter regex="true()" source="$body//Hotel/@HasExtraInfo">
                     <then>
                        <enrich>
                           <source clone="true" type="inline">
                              <ImageCode xmlns="">IMG10004</ImageCode>
                           </source>
                           <target action="child" xpath="$body//Hotel"/>
                        </enrich>
                     </then>
                     <else/>
                  </filter>
                  <loopback/>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </iterate>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="HotelDetails" scope="default">
            <HotelDetails xmlns=""/>
         </property>
         <aggregate id="Hotels">
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="HotelDetails" expression="$body/*[1]">
               <enrich>
                  <source clone="true" xpath="$body/*[1]"/>
                  <target xpath="$ctx:bodyBackup//Response/ResponseDetails/SearchHotelPriceResponse/HotelDetails"/>
               </enrich>
               <enrich>
                  <source clone="true" xpath="$ctx:bodyBackup/*[1]"/>
                  <target type="body"/>
               </enrich>
               <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

For this solution this is the result

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Response ResponseReference="REF_D_028_749-2801486459143247">
         <ResponseDetails Language="en">
            <SearchHotelPriceResponse>
               <HotelDetails>
                  <Hotel HasExtraInfo="false" HasMap="true" HasPictures="true">
                     <City Code="LON">London</City>
                     <Item Code="ALE1">ALEXANDRA</Item>
                     <StarRating>3</StarRating>
                     <HotelRooms>
                        <HotelRoom Code="SB" NumberOfRooms="1"/>
                     </HotelRooms>
                  </Hotel>
                  <Hotel HasExtraInfo="true" HasPictures="true">
                     <City Code="LON">London</City>
                     <Item Code="ALO">Aloft London Excel</Item>
                     <StarRating>4</StarRating>
                     <HotelRooms>
                        <HotelRoom Code="SB" NumberOfRooms="1"/>
                     </HotelRooms>
                     <ImageCode>IMG10004</ImageCode>
                  </Hotel>
                  <Hotel HasExtraInfo="true" HasMap="true" HasPictures="true">
                     <City Code="LON">London</City>
                     <Item Code="AMB3">Ambassadors Bloomsbury</Item>
                     <StarRating>4</StarRating>
                     <HotelRooms>
                        <HotelRoom Code="SB" NumberOfRooms="1"/>
                     </HotelRooms>
                     <ImageCode>IMG10004</ImageCode>
                  </Hotel>
               </HotelDetails>
            </SearchHotelPriceResponse>
         </ResponseDetails>
      </Response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Yep got it! Thanx Ernesto.

Answer (score 1):

Use "foreach" mediator to iterate "Hotel" nodes and inside it's sequence, you can use enrich mediator (that will modify a single node)

Comment: Ok. I'll try this also Jean-Michel. Thanx